# How can I tell why a rollback is happening in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, pyramid

When I insert into MySQL with SQLAlchemy, I see the message "ROLLBACK" appear in the outputed log for the development server.  How can I tell why the rollback is happening?

```
2011-04-10 00:35:32,736 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...4710][MainThread] INSERT INTO pageview (time, unit_id, visitor_id, url_id, referrer_id, reservation_id, visit_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)
2011-04-10 00:35:32,736 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...4710][MainThread] (datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 31, 0, 1, 53), 120L, 5538L, 11075L, 11076L, 5538L, None) 
2011-04-10 00:35:32,737 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...4710][MainThread] ROLLBACK 
Starting server in PID 10158. 
serving on 0.0.0.0:6543 view at http://127.0.0.1:6543
```

I am noticing that the letter "L" appears after every foreign key value (ex: the unit_id field is "120L" instead of "120").  Could that be related to this issue?

Here is the python code that is doing the insert:

```
@classmethod
def unconverted(class_):
    session = DBSession()
    return session.query(class_).filter(class_.pageview == None).order_by(class_.time).limit(5).all()

@classmethod
def convert_all(class_):
    session = DBSession()

    unconverted = class_.unconverted()
    for item in unconverted:

        pageview = PageView(raw_request=item)
        item.pageview = pageview
        session.add(item)

    session.flush()
    transaction.commit()
    session.close()
```

EDIT:

Following the advice of plaes, I get the following exception when doing a try/except on session.flush():

```
2011-04-10 11:33:44,462 INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine.0x...3750][MainThread] ROLLBACK
(IntegrityError) (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`metrics`.`pageview`, CONSTRAINT `pageview_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`unit_id`) REFERENCES `unit` (`id`))') 'INSERT INTO pageview (time, unit_id, visitor_id, url_id, referrer_id, reservation_id, visit_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' (datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 31, 0, 1, 53), 120L, 5608L, 11215L, 11216L, 5608L, None)
```

What is this error occurring?

Comment: The error message is clear. SA takes care of the proper INSERT order of related objects. However what seems to be the case is that you have a FK constraints on the database, but it is probably missing on the SA model. It would help if you posted the model definition extract which covers the *pageview* and *unit* classes/tables.

Comment: Letter L after numbers just means that it is Long integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always print out the error when exception occurs:

```
try:
    transaction.commit()
except Exception, e:
    session.rollback()
    print str(e)
```

Comment: I added that try/except but nothing gets printed out to the console. Does an except always need to be thrown for a rollback to occur?

Comment: Just needed to do it on the flush instead of the commit.  It prints this out:

"(IntegrityError) (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`metrics`.`pageview`, CONSTRAINT `pageview_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`unit_id`) REFERENCES `unit` (`id`))') 'INSERT INTO pageview (time, unit_id, visitor_id, url_id, referrer_id, reservation_id, visit_id) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' (datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 31, 0, 1, 53), 120L, 5608L, 11215L, 11216L, 5608L, None)"

Any ideas what to make of that?

Comment: It's hard to tell unless I can see how your models are set up :S